# Прокрутка до конца при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript

Имею функцию:

```
function scrollDown() {
    var scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    scrollHeight = Math.max(scrollHeight, clientHeight);
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight)
}
```

Как её использовать, чтобы при открытии страницы она пролистывалась вниз?

`<body onload="scrollDown()">` - не работает.

Comment: Обязательно через javascript или можно через jquery?

Comment: Вообще, если честно, хочу обойтись без Jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('bottom').scrollIntoView(true);
}
</script>

<div style="height: 5000px;">Top</div>
<div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
```

Comment: сеньк ю, мне достаточно было строчки window.onload=)